# Issue forwarding email with POSTFIX

Tags: debian, email, postfix

I need that emails arriveds from an external email (example "**user@external_domain.com**"), to an email account on my server (example: "**root@my_domain.com**"), be forwarded to another external address (example: "**end_destination@gmail.com**"). But it not works and no errors on LOG files.

**Domain addresses, emails and IPs changed just to maintain my client's privacy.**

When sending a message from an external email, example **user@external_domain.com**, to an email account on my server, example: **root@my_domain.com**, it arrives correctly in the root email box.

Log below:

```
May 24 18:47:58 mail postfix/smtpd[1711]: connect from a4-salsa4-1.my_domain.com[62.14.x.x] 
May 24 18:47:58 mail postfix/smtpd[1711]: 6C776419DE: client=a4-salsa4-1.my_domain.com[62.14.x.x] 
May 24 18:47:58 mail postfix/cleanup[1715]: 6C776419DE: message-id=<5b07330dc328f5_720f3fc01a2314056420@a434gfdinter9.mail> 
May 24 18:47:58 mail postfix/qmgr[1415]: 6C776419DE: from=<exemplo user@external_domain.com>, size=2087, nrcpt=1 (queue active) 
May 24 18:47:58 mail postfix/smtpd[1711]: disconnect from a4-salsa4-1.my_domain.com[62.14.x.x] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5 
May 24 18:47:58 mail postfix/local[1716]: 6C776419DE: to=<root@my_domain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.07, delays=0.06/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox) 
May 24 18:47:58 mail postfix/qmgr[1415]: 6C776419DE: removed
```

I want the all emails that arrived in "root" account (**root@my_domain.com**) to be forwarded to "**end_destination@gmail.com**", so I configured the routing.

Enabling forward (in the shell with as root user):

```
# echo "\ root end_destination@gmail.com"> ~ / .forward
```

With this setup for routing, emails sent from "**user@external_domain.com**" to email address "**root@my_domain.com**", arrive at the local mail account (at my vps), but do not arrive at "**end_destination@gmail.com**".

However the logs indicate that they have been sent to "**end_destination@gmail.com**", see below the log:

```
May 24 17:58:14 mail postfix/smtpd[32297]: connect from a4-salsa4-1.my_domain.com[62.14.x.x]
May 24 17:58:14 mail postfix/smtpd[32297]: 7A43B41A02: client=a4-salsa4-1.my_domain.com[62.14.x.x]
May 24 17:58:14 mail postfix/cleanup[32301]: 7A43B41A02: message-id=<5b072765eb5c6_8e23febd912113c830b6@a434gfdinter9.mail>
May 24 17:58:14 mail postfix/qmgr[30879]: 7A43B41A02: from=<user@external_domain.com>, size=2087, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 24 17:58:14 mail postfix/smtpd[32297]: disconnect from a4-salsa4-1.my_domain.com[62.14.x.x] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
May 24 17:58:14 mail postfix/cleanup[32301]: 7FD4D41A08: message-id=<5b072765eb5c6_8e23febd912113c830b6@a434gfdinter9.mail>
May 24 17:58:14 mail postfix/qmgr[30879]: 7FD4D41A08: from=<user@external_domain.com>, size=2231, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 24 17:58:14 mail postfix/local[32302]: 7A43B41A02: to=<root@my_domain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.03, delays=0.02/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (forwarded as 7FD4D41A08)
May 24 17:58:14 mail postfix/qmgr[30879]: 7A43B41A02: removed
May 24 17:58:14 mail postfix/smtp[32303]: 7FD4D41A08: to=<end_destination@gmail.com>, orig_to=<root@my_domain.com>, relay=relay.my_vps_host.com[177.153.9.96]:25, delay=0.33, delays=0/0.01/0.31/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as CE14D777DC134)
May 24 17:58:14 mail postfix/qmgr[30879]: 7FD4D41A08: removed
```

When sending a local email to root (for example: crontab jobs), the email arrives successfully at the local account and also at "**end_destination@gmail.com**", see the log:

```
May 24 17:55:03 mail postfix/smtp[32250]: 6E08B41A02: to=<end_destination@gmail.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=relay.my_vps_host.com[177.153.9.96]:25, delay=1.2, delays=0.01/0.02/0.93/0.28, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 6732B777D6711)
May 24 17:55:03 mail postfix/qmgr[30879]: 6E08B41A02: removed
```

I am strongly suspected of having a filter at "**relay.my_vps_host.com**" blocking the messages.

So I opened a check request with the support of my server and they informed me that there is no any kind of lock in the relay ("**relay.my_vps_host.com**").

The emails that should be forwarded simply do not reach at "**end_destination@gmail.com**".

**/etc/postfix/main.cf:**

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
compatibility_level = 2
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated 
defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.my_domain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, my_domain.com,  mail.my_domain.com, localhost.my_domain.com, , localhost
relayhost = relay.my_vps_host.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
```

**/etc/postfix/master.cf:**

```
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       y       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender     $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

The SPF for my_domain.com:

- v=spf1 +a +mx +ptr:my_vps_host.com include:_spf.google.com -all

I'm using:

- Debian 9 (stretch).
- Postfix 3.1.8.

Can someone help get the forwarded email to arrive at "root@my_domain.com"?

Thank you so much!